# Turn on GPS by code

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to switch on GPS by code. The following methode is the code I've used but is does'not work.

Is there any suggestion that i can used

**Method1:**

```
private void turnGPSOn(){
    Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

**Method2:**

```
private void turnGPSOn(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

**Method3:**

```
public void turnGPSOn()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
     intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
     this.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(!provider.contains("gps"))
        { 
        //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

Comment: These are all security flaws that have long since been fixed. Any alternative would be another security flaw that, if the approach still works, would need to get fixed. Apps cannot enable GPS, for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Above 4.0 u can not toggle gps from app directly. As commonsware pointed out these were bugs which were being exploted by developers and are now fixed at Google's end.

Redirect user to settings and when user returns to your app, get the necessary data from gps. If still off redirect user again. Tinder does the same.